# "Multiple Definition Of" Error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I have the following class:

```
class Character
{
public:
    Character();
    Character(std::string char_name, Race char_race, Gender char_gender);
    ~Character();

    int get_id() { return this->char_id; }
    std::string get_name() { return this->name; }
    Race get_race() { return this->race; }
    Gender get_gender() { return this->gender; }

private:
    int char_id;
    static int * char_count;
    std::string name;
    Race race;
    Gender gender;
};
int * Character::char_count = 0;
#endif // CHARACTER_H
```

Note the static field, which is initialized outside of the class.

Here's the implementation:

```
Character::Character()
{
    this->char_id = *char_count;
    char_count++;
}

Character::Character(std::string char_name, Race char_race, Gender char_gender)
{
    this->char_id = *char_count;
    char_count++;
    this->name = char_name;
    this->race = char_race;
    this->gender = char_gender;
}

Character::~Character()
{

}
```

Apparently my compiler doesn't like this. The error produced is "multiple definition of Character::char_count", yet I see no multiple definition.

???

Comment: Post a longer version of the error message.

Comment: Are the include guard `#ifdef`/`#define` really missing in actual code?

Answer (score 4):

The initialization of that static field

```
int * Character::char_count = 0;
```

should be in a .cpp file. Otherwise the following happens: once more than one .cpp file get the .h file included you've got two definitions of the static field and that cuases a link error later. The include guards won't help here - they only prevent multiple inclusion into the same .cpp file, not into different .cpp files.

Comment: hmm.. I tried that, but that still didn't yield much. I have the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Holland: Have you removed the initializer from the .h file?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still nothing :/

Comment: should *only* be in the the `.cpp` file.

Comment: Made sure you really recompiled all files? If it is only within one `.cpp`, it should work

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, forgot to do that. I is noob 0_o. All is well, thank you.